# using ng-mask for phone

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I still have doubt in using ng-mask, I went through most of the web pages for it to work but it still remains the same. And many people told to use it with input tag of angularjs, after doing so Im not able to mask the input.Or am I making mistake please somebody correct me and give the clarity of using the ng-mask.

```
    <input type="tel" name="phoneno" maxlength=13  ng-model="phone.number" ng-mask="(999)999-9999"/>
    </div>          
<button class="button2" ng-click="home()">Back</button> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
<button class="button3" ng-click="addphone()">Add</button>
```

Comment: please show us some code, my magic power is gone for today.

Comment: Would be great to see a piece of code here

Comment: @DmitryEvseev hi I have added the code

Answer (score 2):

Download the ngMask.min.js from net

Call the ngMask.min.js before app.js and Include app.js module

```
var yourApp= angular.module("yourApp", [
'ngMask'
]);
```

HTML :

```
<input type="tel" name="phoneno" maxlength=13 ng-model="phone.number" mask="(999)999-9999" />
```

Comment: Kumar Im not getting the pattern. Should I create any controller or directive to make use of it

Comment: i hope you included ngMask.min.js on page load and added in app.js module

Comment: Can you explain where to include ngMask.min.js , Im sorry for asking you this. @Sambath Kumar

Comment: angularJs with MVC are you using..? @jazzoria

Comment: check the answer @jazzoria

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me.

I think you should use data-on attribute like below

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" data-ng-model="zipcode" placeholder="Enter the zip code" data-ng-mask="#####-###" data-on="keyup">
```

Comment: when I run this code [https://plnkr.co/edit/wnOwrclRda4GHLRwR5bY?p=preview] it didn't generate the pattern 00000-111 instead it takes only numbers like 00000111 @vishal shah

Answer (score 0):

```js
// 2. Add ngMask module dependency to your app.
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngMask']);
```

```html
<!-- 1. Add ngMask plugin after your AngularJS. -->
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='ngMask.min.js'></script>

<!-- 3. Use the avaiable patterns to create your mask. Set the mask attribute. -->
<input type='text' ng-model='maskModel' mask='39/19/9999' />

<!-- 4. Adjust your mask options. -->
<input type='text' ng-model='maskModel' ng-value='0/3/9' mask='3/9?' mask-repeat='2' mask-restrict='accept' mask-clean='true' mask-validate='false' mask-limit='false' />
```

source: https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Use ui-mask instead:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="birth-date">Date of birth</label>
<input type="text"
class="form-control"
id="birth-date"
ng-model="formData.date_of_birth"
ng-value="formData.date_of_birth"
ui-mask="99.99.9999"  
ui-mask-placeholder 
ui-mask-placeholder-char="_"
>
 </div>
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask