# ng-mask not working on Samsung devices in ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I can't get `ng-mask` to work properly on Samsung devices in ionic. The cursor is acting weird. It is working perfectly on other devices

Library Link : 
https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask

```html
<input type="tel" class="mobile_text_field" restrict="reject" clean="true" mask="(999) 999-9999" id="phone"ng-model="user_signup.mobile"placeholder="Type your mobile number here"/>
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717614/using-ng-mask-for-phone

Comment: it's working on Iphone and other android devices but i can't seem to get it right on Samsung products

Comment: You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask. I have tested and it'w working fine in all devices. Use this version  "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.1"

Comment: i'm currently working on angular 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `ng-mask` is intented to work only with `input type="text"`. If you want to prevent typing letters you can use `restrict="reject"`. See the demos: http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/